# I am searchig in wachtos3 a replacement for the inputNode to safe Audiobuffer into a file

Tags: buffer, avfoundation, swift3, microphone, watchos-3

I tried to create a own class but the Classes for the input node aren't available in watchos3.

I tried with AVAudioPlayerNode but it haves error.

have somebody any suggestion how to record the microphone Buffer in watchos3?

Answer (score 0):

You can present an [audio recording view controller with](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628147-presentaudiorecordercontrollerwi):

```
[WKInterfaceController presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL:preset:options:completion:]
```

However the user has to manually hit start and stop.